# When I instantiate a class in PHP, do I get a pointer to the object?

Tags: php, object, instance-variables

Or, does my variable hold the object itself?

When I say for example:

```
$obj = new ClassOne();
```

is the $obj a pointer to the object created in the memory? Does it hold only the memory address to the object? Or does it hold the object itself?

For example when I say,

```
$obj = new SomeOtherClass();
```

Will ClassOne object be garbage collected like in JAVA, or will it cause a memory-leak like in C++?

Comment: I don't think the java, C++ and oop tags are relevant here.

Comment: Sorry, I will remove them. What should I put?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly, the object models in C++ and Java are a bit different:

- C++ has unconstrained variables: Every object type can occur as the type of an object that is a vari­able. In other words, variables can be objects of any type. (But not all va­ri­ables are objects (e.g. re­fe­rences)!) Moreover, all variables are scoped, and thus the lifetime of all objects-that-are-variables is also scoped automatically. Only dynamically-allocated objects can never be variables, and they can only be handled via pointers and references.
- In Java, if we ignore the primitive types, variables are *never* objects, and objects can never be variables. All objects are always "magically somewhere else" (e.g. "the GC heap"), and you can only ever handle them through pointer-like handles. In Java, a *variable* of type `T` is always a reference to the actual object of type `T`, which lives somewhere else. Variables are also scoped, like in C++, but the lifetime of all Java *objects* is indeterminate, and only guaranteed to ex­tend beyond the lifetime of all references to a given object.

  (The situation is different for built-in, "value"-type types like `int`, which *can* occur as the type of variables, and in fact *cannot* be allocated dynamically.)
- I think PHP is similar to Java in that regard.

Comment: Thanks great answer. Then I am assuming, in the above code, the first object is inaccessible, after the second line in the code? I think life is easier with pointers and objects that are variables..

Comment: @KorayTugay: Right, the first object is inaccessible after the second assignment, and will eventually be collected. There aren't any leaks. Which one's easier is a matter of taste. Java is conceptually much less complex than C++, but personally I find the deterministic lifetime of objects in C++ far more compelling. Well, whatever suits your tastes I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/oop5.intro.php) says:

> PHP treats objects in the same way as references or handles, meaning that each variable contains an object reference rather than a copy of the entire object. See Objects and References.

Read the documentation. That's why it has been written.

Comment: So is it garbage collected?

Comment: Yes, it's GCed. Why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

There are no *pointers* in PHP. A variable that holds an object holds an *object identifier* or *object reference*. That's a variable basically of the type `object` with the value `42` (or whatever the internal object identifier is). It is a value that is referencing an object, which is stored somewhere in memory. It's not a pointer or memory address though. Assigning another object to the variable assigns another object identifier to the variable, it does not alter any memory address or the previously assigned object.